# Meteor creating JSON object from json string

Tags: meteor

I need to create a JSON object from a json string. I tried `JSON.parse(json-string)` but I get error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

But when I run the same string in Android `JSONObject(json-string)` I get a no errors

```
HTTP.get(url, function (error, response) {

if (response) {

  var content = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log(content);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Doesn't `response` contains the json-string and nothing else un-modified? Thanks

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: It contains single quote which when I console.log in the terminal, it adds "\" before each single quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response` is an object. You need to `JSON.parse(response.content)` or just `response.data`.

From [official docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call):

> Contents of the result object:
>
> **statusCode** *Number*
>
> Numeric HTTP result status code, or null on error.
>
> **content** *String*
>
> The body of the HTTP response as a string.
>
> **data** *Object or null*
>
> If the response headers indicate JSON content, this contains
>   the body of the document parsed as a JSON object.
>
> **headers** *Object*
>
> A dictionary of HTTP headers from the response.

Comment: Indeed the response headers indicate JSON content. Does that mean I don't need to do 'JSON.parse(response.content)' and just use "data", if so, how is it done? :) thx

Comment: hm... yep. Seems like you can just use `response.data` instead)

Comment: Is there a meteor core JSON api, I could not find but EJSON. I need to extract some array and some object my name.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by `extract some array and some object my name`?

Comment: I mean get values from the JSON object by key. like jsonObj.names() for all the names, jsonObj.getArray("someName") ...etc

Comment: Just get property you need. `JSON.parse(jsonString).someName`. In your case it is simply `response.data.someName`